Wiring led strip on solar cell system
I have following wiring to load batteries using solar power:

Image source: https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B08DY28BXW?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title&th=1
What I want is to wire a led strip so that it is light by the battery when there is no solar power, and by the solar cells otherwise.
This is how I wanted to wire the led strip:

Image source: https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B08DY28BXW?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title&th=1
Is that the way to do ?
Also, is that possible to wire that like the following to add more power to the led strip?

Image source: https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B08DY28BXW?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title&th=1

There's a bit too many questions, but let's try:

If the way you drew it is the way to go, it depends on the LED strip. It is always connected to battery and does not know when there is solar power charging the battery and when there isn't. It is unlikely that this is what you want.

The second way with two panels and chargers will not work. The two batteries are in series to make a 7.2V battery pack. You have two 4.2V chargers in parallel to charge a 7.2V cell. If everything is right, each cell is charged to 2.1V which is dangerously low level for a lithium battery, it may degrade and damage, and damaged batteries are dangerous, they may burst into flames or explode. And, the LED strip still does not know when there is solar power and when there isn't.



No this is not the way to do it.
You must describe the functions and both interface specs to meet your expectations.
Solar Panel output, Voc,Isc, Wmax, expected worst-case solarity or W-s in 1 day.
MPPT regulator output specs or set Vpanel to 82% of Voc loaded from Li Ion charger interface.
Li Ion Charger I/O specs, CC, CV, cutoff, Hysteresis to recharge.  You want to minimize the time during CV or minimize the voltage like 3.8 to 4.0V if enough time for last 20% SOC during the rest of the day.
Li-Ion Ah rating, ESR, quality tests for number of recharge days vs CC CV algorithm ( read Battery University site on this) You don't want to replace batteries every year.
LED Specs with current control vs ambient light from PV or SoC of battery  How long will the light last after 1/2 yr? 1 hr, 2hr? 10 minutes?
What is the Max PV power to LED power ratio? 0.1? 0.2? 0.5? 1 ??
What is overall efficient expectation if you assume 50% is lost charging the battery. What is the efficiency dependent on?
There are so many cheap solar LED lights that are weak after a couple hours because they were poorly designed or used poorly. (wrong angles)
After you review what is your cost budget?
Then start a design.
